# How to make a spinner work with a text field in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, spinner, textfield

I'm currently working on making a simple conversion program and im trying to have the user select from a list             of items "binary, decimal..." from one spinner menu and then select a second choice "binary, decimal.." and then          use the text field to the right of the spinners to input the value and then hit a "convert" button and it spit out           the conversion.

So far, ive been able to build the 2 text fields and the conversion button and have THAT work but, i can't seem to figure out how to make the text fields work with the selection on the spinner menu.

Any suggestions? This is what i currently have---**______**------**______**----- THANKS IN ADVANCE :)

MainActivity

```
package com.overworldinnovations.datatool;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
//import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
//import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
private Button buttonConvert;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    addItemsOnSpinner2();
    addListenerOnButton();
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();   
    }
}

public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
  }

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
  }

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);

    buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        "OnClickListener : " + 
                "\nSpinner 1 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) + 
                "\nSpinner 2 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonConvert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:text="Convert" />

 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />

 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="108dp" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

strings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Data Tool</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="convert">Convert</string>
<string name="data_tool_is_an_application_that_converts_binary_to_decimal_d">Data Tool is an application that converts Binary to Decimal :D</string>
<string name ="country_prompt">Choose a country</string>

<string-array name = "type_arrays">
    <item >Decimal</item>
    <item >Binary</item>
    <item >Hexidecimal</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

CustomOnItemSelectedListener

```
package com.overworldinnovations.datatool;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
        "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }

}
```

Comment: What is it that is not working? What do you mean by "how to make the text fields work with the selection on the spinner menu." ?

Comment: meaning- i want when they select "binary" it works with the binary function and when they select "decimal" it works with the decimal funtion. Almost like google translate works. It knows the difference between english to spanish and spanish to english

Comment: Have you tried using a conditional block in your buttonConvert's OnClickListener that will process the input based on spinner.getSelectedItem() ?

Comment: Im Still fairly new to Eclipse (not new to java) but I'm having a hard time making what ever the person chooses for drop down box 1 and 2 convert to the answer.
Like, i want someone to be able to select- lets say- Inches in the top (first) drop down menu and Centimeters in the bottom (second) drop down menu and to the right of each selection have a text field to the left of the first drop down menu that synced up with the selection and converts it to the second item on the lower drop down menu when you hit convert. Any help at all would be nice. Any help would be nice!